# c++ Debugging Exception c0000139

Tags: c++, exception, debugging, odbc, crash

I am currently trying to get to the bottom of a client crash with one of our applications. I have wrapped the app in an exception handler which creates a mini-dump when the crash occurs.

The application crashes with the exception c0000139 (of which there isn't a huge amount of documentation).

The callstack looks like this

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlRaiseStatus@4()  + 0x26 bytes 
ntdll.dll!_LdrpSnapThunk@32()  + 0x26f48 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_LdrpSnapIAT@16()  + 0xd9 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor@16()  + 0x7a bytes    
ntdll.dll!_LdrpHandleOldFormatImportDescriptors@16()  + 0x2e bytes  
ntdll.dll!_LdrpWalkImportDescriptor@8()  + 0x11d bytes  
ntdll.dll!_LdrpLoadDll@24()  - 0x265 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_LdrLoadDll@16()  + 0x110 bytes   
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryExW@12()  + 0xc8 bytes 
odbc32.dll!_ODBCLoadLibraryEx@12()  + 0x29 bytes    
odbc32.dll!_LoadDriver@12()  + 0x119f bytes 
odbc32.dll!_SQLDriverConnectW@32()  + 0x1be bytes   
odbc32.dll!_SQLDriverConnect@32()  + 0x125 bytes
```

It looks like the program is trying to create a database connection (to Oracle via ODBC) and somehow failing to either find the dll or has found a dll with the wrong entry point.

I was wondering if anyone could offer advice an how to track this problem down further, or if anyone has experienced this problem I'd be interested in hearing how you solved it.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 1):

That exception code is Entry point not found - something is trying to load a DLL and the DLL cannot find all the DLLs it needs.

Use depends.exe to show what the DLL requires.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however how do I find the source dll? As I'm not calling LoadLibrary so I don't really know what dll it's loading.

Comment: I don't think Dependes.exe is going to help me as the dll load is invoked dynamically by the ODBC framework.

Comment: Did you depends.exe on odbc.dll and the oracle dlls ?

Comment: I did indeed and all seemed reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Enable loader snaps (gflags -i yourapp.exe +sls) and have it pinpoint the library its failing to find/load (starting the program under the debugger will spew all the loader diagnostics).

Alternatively, get the name of the library from the crash dump by examining parameters of LoadLibraryExW call.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the crash on my machine. To make matters worse the clients machine where it does crash is in New York and I'm in London. The dump only dumps the stack and memory as it wasn't an option to do a full memory dump.

Comment: Reinstall the oracle driver? Might be quicker than debugging if your access is limited. Or does the ODBC install have a test program to see if it can connect

Comment: To make matters worse the problem is intermittent which really doesn't help. It's also across several users in New York. Because the problem is intermittent I'm not sure a reinstall will help. The oracle drivers that the ODBC loader is trying to load is on a mapped network drive. The only problem I can think is that perhaps the drive mapping is failing. But again that's just guess work ...

Comment: CInstall the drivers on the local hard disk:) Windows does not like network things as much as say Unix - so you need ways of doing remote installs - etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.

Turns out (at least this seems like it was the problem) that we had a configuration problem. Half of the software was set to load the 9i drivers and half of the software was expecting the 10g drivers.

It's early days yet and we need to test this, however it seems very likely that this was the cause.

Cheers
Rich

Answer (score 0):

In my own case I had similar problem.

And root cause was that .dll was loaded from incorrect path - `python27.dll` was residing in `C:\Windows\System32` (1) and in local application directory (2).

Dll from (1) was loaded causing further `(ntdll.dll) in testhost.net472.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.` exception to occur.

Fix was rather simple:

`LoadLibrary(libname);`

was replaced with:

`LoadLibraryExW(libname, nullptr, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);`

This modifies .dll search order to find .dll first from application folder, not system folder.